# Очистка виджета Canvas в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Возможно ли и как стереть все с виджета `Canvas`?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk



class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()
        ########################################
        self.parent.bind("<Configure>", self.resize_event)
        ########################################
        self.update_canvas()

    def initUI(self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.parent, bg="white")
        self.canvas.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

    def draw_canvas(self):
        self.canvas.create_line(0,0,self.canvas.winfo_width(), self.canvas.winfo_height())

    def update_canvas(self):
        self.canvas.update()
        self.remove_place_canvas()
        self.draw_canvas()

    def remove_place_canvas(self):...
        # self.canvas. ...

    def resize_event(self, event):
        self.update_canvas()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = Example(root)
    root.geometry("1000x600")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Метку update лучше заменить на clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы стереть все с виджета Canvas, используйте метод `canvas.delete()`
Чтобы стереть все со всех виджетов Canvas в текущем фрейме, используйте метод `canvas.delete('all')`.

Comment: Спасибо, canvas.delete('all') работает